# HTML inside php condition

Tags: php, html

The following works fine to show a source image.

```
<html>
<h3>First Test</h3>
<img src="example1.php" />
</html>
```

But I wanted to validate user, then only show source image like following,

```
<html>
<h3>First Test</h3>

<?php
some logic = $usermatch
if($usermatch)
<img src="example1.php" />
?>

</html>
```

When I try the same it simply doesn't show image and doesn't accept `<img src="example1.php" />` inside the PHP code.

I am a beginner and just learning php and html.

Could you please guide me how to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Google "PHP alternative syntax"

Comment: `echo '<img src="example1.php" />';` would solve your problem, but you definitely need to follow an advise to google "PHP alternative syntax".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to switch in and out of PHP mode

```
<html>
<h3>First Test</h3>

<?php if($usermatch) { ?>
  <img src="example1.php" />
<?php } ?>

</html>
```

And some like to use echo statements, but you'll see that you get less help from editors when editing the HTML

```
<html>
<h3>First Test</h3>

<?php 

if($usermatch)
     echo '<img src="example1.php" />';
?>
```

Comment: This is the only answer to mention the easiest solution (echo) and also the cleanest looking non-easy solution.

Comment: @Mark I put `echo` in there but I think it makes it harder to read, notice that the HTML syntax isn't highlighted properly in the above snippet.

Comment: I debated usign echo, but felt closing/reopening was clsoer to what he was trying to do.

Comment: @MrGlass I like answers being useful to others besides just the OP so I wanted to add more detail, I prefer the first one.

Comment: @JuanMendes Thats why I added my note about about the interpreter. The formatting is much nicer here though, I got lazy

Answer (score 2):

A little change to your code, although this is rather an ugly way to do it.

```
<?php
some logic = $usermatch
if($usermatch) {
?>
<img src="example1.php" />
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't miss the php *closing* and *opening tags*. Try something like this

```
<?php
some logic = $usermatch
if($usermatch) : ?>
<img src="example1.php" />
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
some logic = $usermatch
if($usermatch) { ?>
  <img src="example1.php" />
<?php
}
?>
```

The problem is that you are mixing your HTML & PHP code. It is perfectly aceptable to have HTML code in your PHP file, but you need to close the PHP code block before so that the interpreter understands that it is not code you intend to run.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well add to all of the answers:

```
<html>
<h3>First Test</h3>

<?php echo $usermatch ? '<img src="example1.php" />' : ''; ?>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<html>
<h3>First Test</h3>

<?php
    some logic = $usermatch
    if($usermatch) {
         print '<img src="example1.php" />'
    }
 ?>

</html>
```

or you can use another way to print html tags in php:

```
<html>
 <h3>First Test</h3>
 <?php
 some logic = $usermatch
      if($usermatch) { 
 ?>
 <img src="example1.php" />
 <?php } ?>
 </html>
```